# How to show an image using QGraphicsView without stretching them

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qimage

I am trying to display an image using QGraphicsView keeping the same ratio when the window is resized. 
i.e. without stretching the image.

Unfortunately I am not succeeding.

I tried searching online a I tried several solutions but none worked.
So I created this mini example so that once solved it will remain a trace of a working solution.
I am using QT 6.6
Any help is welcome!

[image: 1]

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QGraphicsScene>
#include <QtWidgets/QGraphicsView>
#include <QtWidgets/QBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QWheelEvent>

class viewport_t : public QGraphicsView {

  public:

    QTransform matrixWorld;
    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    QImage image;
    QWidget * windows;

    viewport_t(QWidget * arg) : QGraphicsView(arg) {
      windows = arg;
      image.load("/Users/thewoz/Desktop/Lena.png");
      myScene = new QGraphicsScene(arg);
      setScene(myScene);
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event){
      QPainter myPainter(viewport());
      myPainter.setWorldTransform(matrixWorld);
      QRectF target(0, 0, viewport()->width(), viewport()->height());
      QRectF source(0, 0, image.width(), image.height());
      myPainter.drawImage(target, image, source);
      fitInView(myScene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
      QGraphicsView::paintEvent(event);
    }

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event) {
      myScene->setSceneRect(0, 0, event->size().width(), event->size().height());
      return QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
    }

};


class window_t : public QWidget {

public:

  QBoxLayout * myGlobalLayout;
  viewport_t * myView;

  window_t() {
    resize(400, 300);
    myGlobalLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom);
    myGlobalLayout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);
    setLayout(myGlobalLayout);
    myView = new viewport_t(this);
    myGlobalLayout->addWidget(myView, Qt::AlignCenter);
    show();
  }

};


int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  window_t window;
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The general algorithm is: figure out the minimal scale factor along both dimensions, then populate the `target` rectangle with the image scaled by the minimal scale factor. As a bonus you typically want to center the image over the other axis so it's not glued to the left corner of your window.

Comment: Hi @Botje thank you for your response.
I clearly did not understand the part of "populate the target rectangle with the image scaled by the minimal scale factor". Can you give me what other hint?

Comment: Search this site for "scale aspect ratio" there are *tons* of duplicates that all demonstrate the basic algorithm.

Comment: Your usage of QGraphicsView is completely wrong, as you're fundamentally treating it as a standard widget instead of using it as intended. In general, you should never override `paintEvent()` of a graphics view, while *graphics items* should be added to the scene. Just use [`addPixmap()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addPixmap) and in `resizeEvent()` call `fitInView()` (which, by the way, should ***NOT*** be called in `paintEvent()`). I strongly suggest you to read more carefully the [Graphics View Framework documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).

Comment: Also, the `addWidget()` line is wrong: the second argument of [`QBoxLayout::addWidget()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) is the *stretch*, while the alignment is the third. Then, you should normally avoid setting the alignment (especially if you only have one widget) unless you really know what you're doing, because that will result in the widget only expanding up to its `sizeHint()` (no matter if it has an expanding size policy). Considering that the layout you got is probably what you actually wanted, that line should simply be `myGlobalLayout->addWidget(myView);`

Comment: HI @musicamante,  thank you very much for your reply.
I actually didn't notice the error on QBoxLayout::addWidget() at all.
I know that in my example I add only one widget to the QBoxLayout but in the final version of my code I will have more that one. I leave only one in the example not to complicate the situation. About the PointEvent() overload I'm using it because that's how I found it done in an example I was following. I'll try to make changes as you suggested.

Comment: @thewoz As said, that `addWidget()` "works" because the `Qt::AlignCenter` is interpreted as an integer for the stretch argument, it would be fundamentally identical to `addWidget(myView, stretch=132)`. Since QGraphicsView has an `Expanding` size policy, you probably see no difference because all other items in that layout have preferred/fixed size policies (or a maximum height). Still, the point remains: you should not use an alignment as second *positional* argument, and you should only use the alignment as *third* (or keyword) argument only if you specifically need that behavior.

Comment: @thewoz the way you're overriding `paintEvent()` is what is commonly used for standard widgets, where everything is "manually" drawn in the widget. You could have achieved the same result just by subclassing QWidget (and with `QPainter myPainter(this);`). The graphics view isn't used like that (at least, not in its intended approach): you add items to the scene, and the view will draw all the contents of the scene on its own.